# NSUserDefaults returns empty array

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a class Person, which is a model

```
import Foundation

public class Person : NSObject , NSCoding{ 
public var name:String="";
public var gender:Int = 0;
public var status:Int = 0

    override init (){
        super.init()
    }

    public init (name:String, gender:Int){
    self.name=name;
    self.gender=gender;
}    
    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {   }
    public func encodeWithCoder(_aCoder: NSCoder) {   }

}
```

Now when I try to retreive [Person] array I use method `getPersons(arr : String!)` . If there is no data in NSUserDefaults , I create it, put 1 element into it and store using `setPersons()`method.

The problem is that on retrieving I get an array with correct count (1), but the object is not filled, having "" in String and 0 in Int variables.

```
 private func archivePeople (people : [Person]) -> NSData{
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(people as NSArray)
    }

    public func getPersons(arr : String!) -> [Person]{
        var array : [Person] = []
        if let unarchivedObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(arr) as? NSData {
            array = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(unarchivedObject) as? [Person])!
        }

       if array.count == 0 {
            array.append(Person(name: A.DEFAULT_THEIR_NAMES,gender: 0))
            setPersons(arr, people: array)
        }
        return array
    }

    public func setPersons(key: String, people : [Person]){
         let archivedObject = archivePeople(people)
        userDefaults.setObject(archivedObject, forKey: key)
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
```

What is wrong? Do I set or retrieve this in a wrong way?

Comment: What's in the bodies of `init(coder` and `encodeWithCoder(`? Of course you need to add code to encode and decode your properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override properly the `NSCoding` functions.
It should look like something the code below:

```
 required public convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let name: String = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        let gender = aDecoder.decodeInt64(forKey: "gender")
        let status = aDecoder.decodeInt64(forKey: "status")
        self.init(name: name, gender: Int(gender))
        self.status = Int(status)
    }

    public func encodeWithCoder(_aCoder: NSCoder) {   
        _aCoder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
        _aCoder.encode(Int64(self.gender), forKey: "gender")
        _aCoder.encode(Int64(self.status), forKey: "status")
    }
```

Comment: in init() it says Argument passed to call that takes no arguments